# linking boost serialisation static library in XCode 4.5.2 c++ project

Tags: c++, xcode, boost

I’m building an application on Mac OSX 10.8 (Mountain Lion) and I’m getting a linkage error relating to a Boost library (serialisation.a).  I’m using other Boost binaries in the same project and they’re not throwing up any problems, so I’m pretty confident that I’ve built the libraries correctly (I elected to build the entire suite of libraries for the Darwin toolset).  For the same reason, I’m reasonably confident that my linker path is set correctly.  I know there aren’t many Mac developers on this list, but I’m wondering if anybody can offer any suggestions.  The project is handled by XCode 4.5.2 and uses the GCC 4.2 compiler.  The following is the output from the build (I’ve only included the first error – all of the rest are variations on a theme and all refer to Boost::archive or Boost::serialisation (both of which are contained within the Boost serialisation.a static library file).

```
Ld /Users/tim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SurfaceReader-fwryryuvfvwihnglkuymbbjtxpac/Build/Products/Debug/SurfaceReader.app/Contents/MacOS/SurfaceReader normal x86_64
    cd /Users/tim/Developer/SurfaceReader
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.8
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -L/Users/tim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SurfaceReader-fwryryuvfvwihnglkuymbbjtxpac/Build/Products/Debug -L/users/tim/developer/libraries/boost_1_50_0/lib -L/users/tim/developer/libraries/cryptopp561 -F/Users/tim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SurfaceReader-fwryryuvfvwihnglkuymbbjtxpac/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/tim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SurfaceReader-fwryryuvfvwihnglkuymbbjtxpac/Build/Intermediates/SurfaceReader.build/Debug/SurfaceReader.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SurfaceReader.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -L/Users/tim/developer/libraries/wxwidgets-2.9.4/build-debug/lib -framework IOKit -framework Carbon -framework Cocoa -framework AudioToolbox -framework System -framework OpenGL /Users/tim/developer/libraries/wxwidgets-2.9.4/build-debug/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-2.9.a /Users/tim/developer/libraries/wxwidgets-2.9.4/build-debug/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_webview-2.9.a /Users/tim/developer/libraries/wxwidgets-2.9.4/build-debug/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_qa-2.9.a /Users/tim/developer/libraries/wxwidgets-2.9.4/build-debug/lib/libwx_baseu_net-2.9.a /Users/tim/developer/libraries/wxwidgets-2.9.4/build-debug/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_html-2.9.a /Users/tim/developer/libraries/wxwidgets-2.9.4/build-debug/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_adv-2.9.a /Users/tim/developer/libraries/wxwidgets-2.9.4/build-debug/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_core-2.9.a /Users/tim/developer/libraries/wxwidgets-2.9.4/build-debug/lib/libwx_baseu_xml-2.9.a /Users/tim/developer/libraries/wxwidgets-2.9.4/build-debug/lib/libwx_baseu-2.9.a -framework WebKit -lexpat -lwxregexu-2.9 -lwxtiff-2.9 -lwxjpeg-2.9 -lwxpng-2.9 -lz -lpthread -liconv -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework CoreMIDI -framework CoreAudio -framework Cocoa -lboost_filesystem -lboost_iostreams -lboost_serialization -lboost_system -lcryptopp -o /Users/tim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SurfaceReader-fwryryuvfvwihnglkuymbbjtxpac/Build/Products/Debug/SurfaceReader.app/Contents/MacOS/SurfaceReader

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

  "boost::archive::basic_xml_iarchive<boost::archive::xml_wiarchive>::load_start(char const*)", referenced from:
      void boost::archive::basic_xml_iarchive<boost::archive::xml_wiarchive>::load_override<std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > >(boost::serialization::nvp<std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > > const&, int)in SurfaceFrame.o
```

Comment: I see that you use the libc++ as the standard library. Did you compile boost also with libc++?

Comment: Not sure how I'd tell.  I'm a novice on this platform - I used ./b2, but didn't specify a linker to use

Comment: You can try to compile your project in C++98 standard if you don't use C++11 features. Under project settings set _Language Dialect_ to C++98 and under _Standard Library_ select libstdc++. Alternatively you will have to look at boost documentation to find out how to compile it with C++11 and link against libc++.

Comment: @TimBurgess - Did you ever get this resolved?  I'm getting same error.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Changing **Apple LLVM Standard Compiler 4.2 - Language** / **C++ Standard Library** setting from *libc++ (LLVM)* to *libstdc++ (GNU)* solved the same case for me.